# Dynamic allocation of date in datepicker

Tags: html, jquery

Restricting date in datepicker in jquery.
Hi, I want a datepicker with following functionality.
Lets assume today's date:

1. Only current and next month should be active. (Already did and working fine).
2. If current date is less than September then last year December should be active (only December) and if current date is greater than September then last year December should be deactivated.

Ex: If today is May 2023 then -> May 2023,June 2023 and December 2022 should be active.
If today is Oct 2023 then -> Oct 2023,Nov 2023 should be active and December 2022 should be deactivated.

I tried creating an array with ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09"] and if current month in this array then activate december but how can I apply this attribute to datepicker is the problem.
Please help.

Comment: Hi Lionheart - please create a minimal, reproducible, testable example that we can debug. Otherwise you are asking too much of us (since we would have to do that ourselves to demonstrate the solution).  Please edit your question and press Ctrl + M *(that will open a jsFiddle-like interface where you can paste a code example that we can experiment with)*.